# ArcGIS Silverlight API - Use POST instead of GET

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, rest, silverlight

Is there a way to get queries performed using the ArcGIS API for Silverlight to use POST instead of GET?  I'm trying to pass in a geometry which has too many vertices for the character limit.

Comment: Could you generate your own AJAX request instead of using the built-in functions (assuming that is what you're doing)?  Like create a custom query function and call that instead of the standard one.

Comment: I could try that or use the SOAP API method if needed.  I would definitely prefer to keep using the Silverlight API if possible.

Comment: I have been developing with the JavaScript API, and there is a nice module in there that handles sending requests.  It is Esri.Request, and it handled requesting data from an ArcGIS Server service better than when I was using the XMLHttpRequest module that is built into JS.  I tried a quick search and didn't see a Silverlight equivalent, but ESRI usually has a lot of the same modules in all applications.  Might help out?